# document.referrer sometimes returns blank value

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

Page A contains a `DetailsList`, which has links to different pages.
Page B contains a file viewer web part.

Clicking on any of the links on "Page A" `DetailsList` row items, directs the user to "Page B".

I am trying to fetch the Page A url using `document.referrer` but it returns a blank value. Rarely it gives the correct url.

Is there any way to ensure the `document.referrer` returns the correct url?

Answer (score 0):

- Since version 85 of Chrome, the default referrer policy has changed from **no-referrer-when-downgrade** to **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**.
- **document.referrer** will only work if the person got to the current page through a link, or clicking something.... not if they were redirected through other means.
- If you rely on the referrer header for your API, best is to specify the **referrerPolicy** for these calls as follows:

```
await ctx.httpClient.post(creatorUrl, HttpClient.configurations.v1, {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer-when-downgrade', // Provide `referrerPolicy` option for falling back to the previous default
  body: JSON.stringify(msg)
});
```

Refer the below article for more details.

- [watch-referrer-header](https://www.eliostruyf.com/watch-referrer-header-spfx-chrome-85-higher/)

Comment: I understand that clicking a link is required. In my case too I click on a link to navigate to a different page. I'll try specifying the referrerPolicy.